# Como transformar v-on:click=“sync” em algo automático que seja disparado ao abrir o html

Tags: javascript, mysql, html5, intel-xdk, vue.js

**Explicação do problema**

Tenho este javascript que no html eu chamo `v-on:click="sync"` ele atualiza a lista de noticias, mas esta lista de noticias enquanto eu não clicar em sync ela fica em branco, por isso estou buscando uma forma de tornar o `v-on:click="sync"` em algo automático que quando eu abra o HTML a lista de noticias seja atualizada automaticamente.

**O JavaScript a seguir**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady(){
var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data:{
            noticias: []
        },
        methods:{
            sync:function(){
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'http://example/read.php',
                    success:function(dados){
                        localStorage.setItem('noticias',JSON.stringify(dados));
                        vm.setNoticias();
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("ocorreu um erro durante a conexão com o servidor!");
                    }
            });
        },
        setNoticias:function(){
            this.noticias = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('noticias'));
            console.log(this.noticias);
        }
    },
    ready:function(){
     this.setNoticias();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: Sugiro a edição do título. Ele pode ser mais descritivo do que está atualmente.

Comment: Você está usando que versão do vue? 1 ou 2?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tirar da função a criação do `vm` e logo após chamar a função:

```
var vm = new Vue({...});

vm.setNoticias();
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais especifico? não entendi bem oque você quis dizer

Comment: Você pega a sua função de criação `var vm = new Vue({...})`, coloca em um script separado, logo após as importações do `Vue`. No final do seu `script` você chama a função `vm.setNoticias();`

Comment: Poderia postar um exemplo mais claro?

Comment: @YuriRuan seu script ficará [assim](http://pastebin.com/8CdbnLDA) e vc deve colocar a `tag` `script` pra ele apenas após a importação da biblioteca `vue`